# Given a Number X (say, 24770). How do I find which powers of 2 it's been incremented by?

Tags: math

The problem i'm having is I've got a number 24770. There are several options on the server that can change this number by a power of 2. How do I know which powers it's been incremented by easily? 
Would converting to binary help in this situation? 
For example, given 24794 is it possible to easily see that 24770+2^3+2^4 was added here? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know anything about the numbers before they are incremented? Are there any limitations on those numbers? If not, what you ask is not possible.

Comment: I have the base number, and the ceiling is 28634 so far. It could be a combination of some or all of the powers of 2 to get to that ceiling but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 24770 is always the same, it sounds like a red herring to obscure the problem. Just subtract that from the final number and it becomes a much simpler question of "which powers of two is this number made from?" (hint: look at the bit positions).

Comment: Will it give me the correct powers though? Silly question but if it's 2^4, vs. 2^8, etc. I'd need the exact combination of powers of 2 to get there, i'm not sure if there would be multiple permutations that could lead to that equivalent or not.

Comment: Unless they're adding the same powers of two multiple times, each one will only "set" a single bit in the subtracted number.

Comment: I'll give this a shot! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

All integers can be expressed by a sum of powers of two. That's the basis of binary numbers.

For instance, the number 24794 is binary 110000011011010. Every 1 means `+2^(position)`. In other words, you're looking at `2^14 + 2^13 + 2^7 + 2^6 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^1`.

Therefore, any number can be the result of any other number incremented by any power of two. You might be trying to solve an equation with too many unknowns here.

Of course, the matter is different if it's always the *same* number that's being incremented by *one* power of two.

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit-wise solvable question I think.

24864 - 24770 = 94 (01011110)

which means 1000000 (2^6) + 10000 (2^4) + 1000 (2^3) + 100 (2^2) + 10 (2^1).

Take use of the class `BitArray`, it may help.